# Fix Illegal string offset after PHP update

Tags: php, arrays, string, php-5.6

I updated my PHP version, and have been getting this error on most of my pages:

> Warning: Illegal string offset in "..." on line 236

After googling and trouble-shooting for hours, I've found that the error is because a variable within an array is being read as a string. I'm clueless as to how to fix this. Please help!

This is the line of code that is causing the error:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['email']) && $_SESSION['email']['loggedIn']){ ... } else { ... }
```

Comment: Which versions are we talking about here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be because `$_SESSION["email"]` contains a string, not an array so `$_SESSION["email"]["loggedIn"]` fails.

You should check first `is_array($_SESSION["email"])`

`if(isset($_SESSION['email']) && is_array($_SESSION["email"] && $_SESSION['email']['loggedIn'])`

Answer (score 0):

The upgrade just turned on error reporting/error display which was off in your previous version, but this was still an error.  This will check that it is set and that it is not empty (`''`, `false`, `null` or `0`):

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['email']['loggedIn'])) {
```